# How to fix an "Unable to Marshal Value" error

Tags: android, gallery, marshalling

When I am trying to open Gallery from my Android App on click of a Button. It is throwing an `"Unable to marshal value"` exception. Below is the code that gives me the error.

At the first try there is no error while opening the gallery. After some clicks if I go to that particular fragment and click on the Select Image icon it is throwing error.

```
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY){
        if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY);

        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Permission not Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return;
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK  && data != null){
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            productImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

The error I am getting:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.smartdisplay, PID: 24822
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.example.smartdisplay.DisplayData@bb07760
>           at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1508)
>           at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:820)
>           at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1455)
>           at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:732)
>           at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1423)
>           at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1133)
>           at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:772)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(FragmentState.java:124)
>           at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1338)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:639)
>           at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1527)
>           at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1433)
>           at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:732)
>           at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1423)
>           at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1133)
>           at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:772)
>           at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3685)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3865)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24822 SIG: 9 Application terminated.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your error is telling you the class `DisplayData` does not implement `Parcelable` iirc

Comment: Thank you @Blundell. It is working fine.